# How to achieve constexpr pseudopolymorphism?

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, parametric-polymorphism

In a ray tracing project that I'm trying to make compile-time (constexpr) for fun and challenge, I've run into a bit of an issue: I have an object (intersection) that needs to refer to one of a group of other objects (shapes).

Now, my understanding is that you cannot use polymorphism / virtual methods with constexpr because of the vtable lookups, so as far as I know, I cannot have a superclass, `Shape`, from which the other classes derive. Thus, I need to make `Intersection` a template class that holds one of its shapes.

Unfortunately, I need to store these `Intersection` classes in an array or some other container, and I want to be able to call a common function on them and their shape, i.e. where the pseudopolymorphism comes in.

I implemented something that solves the problem, where I take an `std::array` of `std::variant` and whenever I add to the array, if the type isn't represented by anything in the `std::variant`, then I expand it. I can also achieve pseudopolymorphism by using `std::visit`, invoking a commonly named function on each element to result in an `std::array` of final elements.

My implementation is here, in this gist. I thought it would be too long to post:

https://gist.github.com/sraaphorst/28998c109f94a78616e7dd488c1491d1

Now, I've been known to solve problems with much more difficulty than is necessary, so I was wondering if any of you know of a simpler way to achieve this?

Comment: It seems to me that you should post this question in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you considered posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it, being fairly new here. I'll go ahead and do that. Thank you both for the suggestion.